# How to ensure a knockout observable array remains sorted?

Tags: arrays, sorting, knockout.js, momentjs

I have an array of objects stored in an `observableArray`, Each array item is a object of moment.js dates.

`{startDate:momentObject, endDate:momentObject, cycle:null}`

I need to compute two things. One will be average time between **startDates**. I think the easiest way to do this will be to calculate the duration between the earliest and latest startDates in the array and divide that by the total number of entries.

I also need the period between 2 startDates. A quick solution I came up with was something like this:

```
$.each(dateArray, function(index, item){
    var previousItem = dateArray[index - 1];

    if(previousItem){

      // since these are moment objects, just use the diff method
      return item.cycle = previousItem.startDate.diff(item.startDate, 'days');
    }

    return false;
});
```

But this will require the `observableArray` to be sorted in ascending order. So here's my question(s).

1. How do I ensure that the `observableArray` is *forcefully* sorted everytime I push a new item to it?
2. Is there a better way to calculate the periods in between `startDates` and the median period?
3. Perhaps, I could compute the period while adding an item to the array instead of the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a subscription event handler to the obervableArray, like this:

```
self.MyArray = ko.observable([]);
var myArraySubscription = self.MyArray.subscribe(onMyArrayChange);

function onMyArrayChange(){
    //Remove the subscription before sorting, to prevent an infinite loop
    myArraySubscription.dispose();
    myArraySubscription = null;

    //Force a sort of the array here. 
    self.MyArray.sort();//NOTE: You need to define your sorting logic here...this line is just a placeholder

    //Re-subscribe
    myArraySubscription = self.MyArray.subscribe(onMyArrayChange);
}
```

Comment: Ah, nice solution with the dispose/resubscribe. My solution was to have a flag in an extender to know when not to re-sort.

Answer (score 4):

If you data-bind your view to a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) that is dependent on your date array you can run your sorting logic on the array each time your date array updates.

```
this.dateArray = ko.observableArray([]);

this.sortedDates = ko.computed(function() {
    var dates = this.dateArray();

    //... do sorting stuff on dates ...

    return dates;

}, this);
```

Comment: I'd like to add that when sorting an array, remember that the `sort` function sorts the original array rather than a copy. There are a few ways to make a copy of an array, but I believe `[].concat(array)` is the fastest.

Comment: My concern is not the view actually. I am afraid that this array might get quite large and having to loop through and sort the array get a little resource hungry after awhile.
No way to do this when an item is added?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using Knockout's extend feature is:

```
  var unwrap = ko.utils.unwrapObservable;

  ko.extenders.sorted = function(target, key) {
    /*

    You may pass in a function, that will be used as the comparison
    function, or a key, that will be used as the attribute upon
    which we will sort.

    The value (unwrapped, if applicable) must have a valueOf() method,
    so we can compare using that.

    */

    var sortFunction;

    if (typeof key === 'function') {
      sortFunction = key;
    } else {
      sortFunction = function(a,b) {
        return unwrap(a[key]) - unwrap(b[key]);
      };
    }

    // We want to prevent our subscription firing when
    // we are already in the process of doing a sort.
    var sorting = false;

    target.subscribe(function sortSubscribe(newValue) {
      if (sorting) {
        return;
      }
      if (target().length > 1) {
        sorting = true;
        // We need to sort the observableArray, not the underlying
        // array. We could do the latter, but then would need to call
        // notifySubscribers() anyway.
        target.sort(sortFunction);
        sorting = false;
      }
    });

    return target;
  };
```

Example usage is:

```
foo = ko.observableArray([]).extend({sorted: 'key'})
foo.push({key: 'value1'})
foo.push({key: 'value0'})

foo() --> [{key: 'value0'},{key: 'value1'}]
```